# How to find median of values within the same group?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, median, worksheet-function, worksheet

[Median help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Letsv.png)

Hi there, I'm trying to find the median of the values (Price) that share the same group (Quarter) as in the picture I have included. I have colour-coded them to show their corresponding values and included example medians on the right-hand side. I hope this makes my question easier to understand.

I need to do this for a larger column where the Quarters are changing. Is it possible to automate this process? If so, what kind of formula would I need to input where the '?' is placed as seen in the bottom right-hand corner?

Also, would it work on a column where the group (Quarter) is not sorted like in the picture?

Thank you for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for your purposes, instead of listing median along side data, this formula takes a list of unique the quarters in your range and calcualtes the median for each corresponding quarter.

All you have to do here is change the quarter and price range, `A2:A7` and `B2:B7` in my example, to line up with your data.

This formula will work no matter what order the quarters are in.

```
=+LET(
quarters,(B2:B7),
prices,(A2:A7),
uniqueQuarters, UNIQUE(quarters),
median, BYROW(uniqueQuarters,LAMBDA(x,MEDIAN(IF(quarters=x,prices)))),
CHOOSE({1,2},uniqueQuarters,median))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help!

I have done as you told and changed the (A2:A7) and (B2:B7) to the appropriate columns. However, I get a #NAME? error for the median values.

I have double-checked the values and groups and they are definitely within the correct range. The formula correctly identifies the unique Quarters in the whole column.

On Function Arguments, it identifies the =UNIQUE and =BYROW functions as #NAME?. I have attached a screenshot of this error. Could it be an incompatibility with my version of Excel? I am using MS Office 2021 if this is any help to you.

Thank you!

Comment: [Here is the screenshot for the above!](https://imgur.com/a/sgQUmY1)

Comment: Just would like to add an update: I managed to make this formula work on the web-based version of Excel where the latest functions are made available. Apparently, I needed a different version of MS Office (Office 365) and opt-in for the Insider Program to use the BYROW function (?).

Nonetheless, thank you for your help! This formula worked in the end for me. I wish I could upvote you but seems like I require some reputation points (new to StackOverflow here). Cheers!

Comment: No problem! The latest production channel for desktop Excel/Microsoft 365 will have this function available, specifically versions greater than or equal to: 16.0.14729.20260 for Windows. `LAMBDA` is one of the most powerful updates to Excel in recent years, I would highly recommend upgrading!